# Yaakov complaining to Pharaoh about his life

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayigash

This is Ramban's questions on the reason and benefit of Yaakov complaining to Pharaoh about his life ([Gen 47, 9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.47.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Nikkud&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)):

> "וַיֹּאמֶר יַעֲקֹב אֶל־פַּרְעֹה יְמֵי שְׁנֵי מְגוּרַי שְׁלֹשִׁים וּמְאַת שָׁנָה מְעַט וְרָעִים הָיוּ יְמֵי שְׁנֵי חַיַּי וְלֹא הִשִּׂיגוּ אֶת־יְמֵי שְׁנֵי חַיֵּי אֲבֹתַי בִּימֵי מְגוּרֵיהֶם׃
>
> And Jacob answered Pharaoh, “The years of my sojourn [on earth] are one hundred and thirty. Few and hard have been the years of my life, nor do they come up to the lifespans of my fathers during their sojourns.”

Ramban:

> לא ידעתי **טעם הזקן אבינו מה מוסר הוא שיתאונן אל המלך** ומה טעם לאמר ולא השיגו את ימי שני חיי אבותי

Doesn't this behavior contradict ([Kid 40](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=30088)) "תוהה על הראשונות" - whoever regrets the Mitzvos he's done, for everything Yaakov did was on [some divine] purpose?

Comment: Do you all -1 Ramban?

Answer (score 0):

He's not saying "I wish I hadn't been good." Pharaoh sees he looks so utterly worn and haggard that Pharaoh can't help but ask -- *good gracious, how old are you already?!* Jacob then replies "well here's the number, and if I look worn-down, it's because I had a tough life."

Comment: 1. Yaakov wasn't asked that he complained by himself. 2. It sounds כפוי טובה toward Hashem 3. You can put it into comments, not an answer. 4. Ramban asks that and I agree with him, just by saying he's not you're not answering anything.